# Django unique_together creates an index without UNIQUE constraint

Tags: mysql, django, indexing, unique

I have a model:

```
class MyModel(models.Model)
    class Meta:
        unique_together=["a", "b"]
        index_together=["a", "b"]
    a=models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    b=models.ForeignKey("othermodel")
```

Migrations for this model:

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    dependencies = [
        ('app', 'previous_migration'),
    ]
    operations = [
        migrations.AlterUniqueTogether(
            name='mymodel',
            unique_together=set([('a', 'b')]),
        ),
        migrations.AlterIndexTogether(
            name='mymodel',
            index_together=set([('a', 'b')]),
        ),
    ]
```

`./manage.py sqlmigrate app mymigration`

```
BEGIN;
CREATE INDEX `app_mymodel_id_asdfasfd_idx` ON `app_mymodel` (`a`, `b`);

COMMIT;
```

And i am using a MySQL database.

Django (1.8.5) now creates an index over both fields together, but with type `INDEX` and not type `UNIQUE`, which does not result in the expected `IntegrityError` when saving a duplicate. Manually changing the index results in the correct behaviour.

With just the `AlterUniqueTogether` migration, i get an empty output for `/manage.py sqlmigrate`.

How do i tell Django to create an `UNIQUE` index? Or is there a good reason why the created index is not setup this way?

Comment: how does the migration look like? what does `DESCRIBE TABLE` say?

Comment: <snide-remark>Another example of a third party software getting in the way?</snide-remark>

Comment: A uniqueness constraint makes a `UNIQUE KEY`, so don't also make another index with the same columns.

Comment: I can reproduce, that i can still save a duplicate Key, if i do not change the constraint via SQL. I add the migration to the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With django 1.8 and a fresh installation with `syncdb` of the app, all needed indexes are created. I currently cannot reproduce the issue, as the old installation has the index manually created and fresh installations create it with `syncdb` and with `migrate` without any problems.

I did not test more recent django yet, but i assume it works as well.